# Treat c++ string as a pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Disclaimer -- I'm coming from a pretty strictly C background.

How can the STL and `std::string` instead of `char*` be used to go about jumping around a string like this (admittedly nonsensical) example?

```
const char* s = "XXXXXXXXhello";
while (*s == 'X') 
    s++;

s += 2;
std::cout << --(--s); //prints `hello`
```

Comment: x y problem, tell us why you want to do it

Comment: okay, updated question a bit. tell me if that helps

Comment: It sounds like `substr()` is a more appropriate solution to your problem. You should also learn about iterators and functions like `begin()` and `end()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to do is modify the object, and get rid of "**h**":

```
std::string s = "hello";
s = s.substr(1); // position = 1, length = everything (npos)
std::cout << s;  //"ello"
```

or

```
std::string s = "hello";
s.erase(0, 1); // position = 0, length = 1
std::cout << s;  //"ello"
```

Comment: If you're modifying the original, `s.erase(0, 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

perfer @José 's second answer and no need to modify the original str

just `std::cout<<s.substr(1)<<endl`

to the edited question:

```
std::string s = "hello world!";
cout<<s.substr(s.find_first_of('e'))<<endl; // == "ello world!"
```

man std::string:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump around without modifying the string, you can either use indices or an iterator:

```
std::string const s("XXXXXXXXhello");

int idx = 0;
while ( s[idx] == 'X' ) 
    ++idx;

idx += 2;
std::cout << &s[idx -= 2] << '\n';
```

The iterator version:

```
auto it = s.begin();
while (*it == 'X')
    ++it;

it += 2;
std::cout << &*it << '\n';
```

Since C++11 it is guaranteed that `std::string` is stored with null terminator in place, so you can use `&` to output the tail of the string. In old code bases you will need to index from `s.c_str()` instead.

Comment: Will either of these actually effectively "shorten" the string in the same way as having the variable point at a new 'beginning' of the string?

Comment: @galois they are a similar effect, you look at a tail slice of the string without modifying the storage